# Unable to push to local, remapped registry using podman

Tags: podman

Using podman 3.0.1, I have in /etc/containers/registries.conf.d/500-insecure-registries.conf (I'm not really using example.com; instead there is a real domain name in there):

```
[[registry]]
location = 'localhost:5000'
prefix = 'example.com'
insecure = true
```

I have an image that has been tagged as follows:

```
podman tag docker.io/library/hello-world example.com/hello-world
```

But when I try to push the image as follows (intending the localhost repository):

```
podman push example.com/hello-world
```

I receive an error that indicates it is actually trying to push to example.com as the location:

```
Error: error copying image to the remote destination: Error trying to reuse blob sha256:9c27e219663c25e0f28493790cc0b88bc973ba3b1686355f221c38a36978ac63 at destination: error pinging docker registry example.com: invalid status code from registry 404 (Not Found)
```

==================================

Based on what I read at https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/manage-container-registries under "Remapping references", the push should go to the local registry... so does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, and found [this issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/4765#issuecomment-570545089). As explained in the comment:

"Redirection and mirroring only happens when pulling, **not when pushing** or logging in."

It's an expected behaviour. When you push the image, it should be tagged as localhost:5000/hello-world. Then you should be able to pull it as example.com/hello-world.

Answer (score 0):

When you tag an image the destination name is the registry where it will be pushed. If you don't want to push to 'example.com,' then tag appropriately:

```
podman tag docker.io/library/hello-world <registry-server>/hello-world
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this approach with good results.  It will still try to fallback to the main `registry.location` if the mirror cannot be found, or refuses access, but will always prefer the mirror if it is available.

```
[[registry]]
# The image prefix to match against the referenced image.
location = "example.com"

# The alternative sources to attempt to pull from first (will fallback to
# registry.location if the image can't be pulled from the mirrors).
[[registry.mirror]]
# The locally hosted server.
location = "localhost:5000"
```

You can also add multiple mirrors this way.  For example, you might want to host a registry locally for testing, and one remotely for backup/proxying: When the local one is running, push and pull from that, but if it isn't then fallback to the proxy, and only try to interact with `example.com` if the other two aren't reachable.

```
[[registry]]
location = "example.com"
[[registry.mirror]]
location = "localhost:5000"
[[registry.mirror]]
location = "proxy.example.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the list of your images

```
podman images
```

although the error is thrown when pushing the image, it looks like it is created, so it might be already there. I think it is a bug in podman  because I get the same error as you do but when I check the images in my local registry the image shows up. I tested it with another image with pytorch and I was able to create the container from the image in my local registry and get inside the container.